# scala Bloxroz assignment solution error

Tags: scala

I am solving week 7 assignment of scala course on coursera. I have created functions that are core to the solution, but it is failing the test case.

Here is my from() function:

```
def from(initial: Stream[(Block, List[Move])],
           explored: Set[Block]): Stream[(Block, List[Move])] = initial match {

    case Stream() => Stream.Empty
    case head #:: rest => {
        val unfilteredSequences = neighborsWithHistory(head._1, head._2)
       val nextSequences = newNeighborsOnly(unfilteredSequences, explored)
       Stream.concat(rest, from(nextSequences, explored ++ nextSequences.map( entry => entry._1)))
    }
  }


def neighborsWithHistory(b: Block, history: List[Move]): Stream[(Block, List[Move])] = {

    def neighborHistoryHelper(xs: List[(Block, Move)], hist: List[Move], acc: List[(Block, List[Move])]): List[(Block, List[Move])] = xs match{
      case Nil => acc
      case tuple :: rest => neighborHistoryHelper(rest, tuple._2 :: hist, acc :+ (tuple._1, tuple._2 :: hist))
    }

    neighborHistoryHelper(b.legalNeighbors, history, Nil).toStream
  }



def newNeighborsOnly(neighbors: Stream[(Block, List[Move])],
                       explored: Set[Block]): Stream[(Block, List[Move])] = {

    def newNeighborHelper(n: Stream[(Block, List[Move])],
                          expl: Set[Block] , acc: Stream[(Block, List[Move])] ) : Stream[(Block, List[Move])] = n match{
      case Stream.Empty => acc
      case head #:: rest => {
        if(expl contains head._1)
          newNeighborHelper(rest, expl , acc )
        else
          newNeighborHelper(rest, expl + head._1, acc :+ head)
      }
    }

    newNeighborHelper(neighbors, explored, Stream.empty)
  }
```

Idea is to process the head and append the possible sequences to rest of the stream.

Here is the test case that fails:

```
    test("optimal solution for level 1") {
    new Level1 {
      assert(solve(solution) == Block(goal, goal))
    }
  }
```

Here is the current result:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at scala.collection.immutable.Stream$Cons.tail(Stream.scala:1233)
```

I suspect this method to be the reason, not sure why.

```
def isLegal: Boolean = b1.row > -1 && b1.col > -1 && b2.row > -1 && b2.col > -1 && b1.row <= b2.row && b1.col <= b2.col
```

Please let me know what is wrong with my solution. I can provide more information if required.

**Updated** Adding terrain function, I suspect even this might be having issue.

```
def terrainFunction(levelVector: Vector[Vector[Char]]): Pos => Boolean = {

    Pos => {
      if(Pos.row >= levelVector.size || Pos.col >= levelVector(0).size || Pos.row <0 || Pos.col <0 )
          false
      else
        levelVector(Pos.row)(Pos.col) != '-'
    }
  }
```

**Code Corrections**

```
def terrainFunction(levelVector: Vector[Vector[Char]]): Pos => Boolean = {

    Pos => {
      if(Pos.row <0 || Pos.col <0  || Pos.row >= levelVector.size || Pos.col >= levelVector(Pos.row).size )
          false
      else
        levelVector(Pos.row)(Pos.col) != '-'
    }
  }

def isLegal: Boolean = terrain(b1) && terrain(b2)
```

With these changes, I am getting wrong answer, it is not giving stack overflow error.

Here is the result:

```
- optimal solution for level 1 *** FAILED ***
[info]   Block(Pos(1,1),Pos(1,1)) did not equal Block(Pos(4,7),Pos(4,7)) (BloxorzSuite.scala:70)
```

I still have some issue somewhere. Hard to understand the issue here.

Comment: So a "legal" position almost everything (within the limits of `Int`) that isn't negative? That sounds like a (near) infinite playing terrain.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So my constraint is indeed the issue?

Comment: @jwvh: I have corrected two functions, not I am not sure how to detect the issue.